# why does browser shows XML parsing error when I use ajax call with dataType as 'text'?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml

I made an AJAX call to a servlet printing just simple plain text and browser shows 'XML PARSING ERROR' and I've already used dataType as 'text'

```
var portNumber = $("#portNumber").val();
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "serverServlet",
            data: {port : portNumber},
            dataType: 'json'
       });
```

Comment: I've tried changing dataType to 'text' once and then to 'json' but same problem.

Comment: whats the response mime type?

Comment: response mime type is just text/plain